# Meaning of the CRM Appointment Icons

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, appointment, dynamics-crm-365

I don't understand what the second icon in the image below for an appointment. Does it mean something is wrong with the appointment?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a big image? I'm unclear which view or form in Dynamics is showing these icons. My guess is the first one indicates a recurring appointment. Not sure about the second one. It could be a button to cancel recurrance or indicate it's not a recurring appointment.

Comment: Are you sure this is not your custom activity icon?

Comment: It's a recurring appointment

Comment: This icon corresponds to Recurring Exceptions. Here is a document which gives more details on what are Recurring exceptions and how they are created - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/create-recurring-appointment-series-instance-exception#create-a-recurring-appointment-exception

Answer (score 1):

Woo hoo. I found this. This is nothing but completed Recurring appointments.

Here are the repro steps:

1. Create a new appointment. Make it as a recurring one by setting "Recurrence"
2. Recurring Appointment screen will open. Save it
3. You will see "End series" button in command bar. Click & End it with "Complete" option
4. That's it, you will see this icon (I checked in Advanced find list)

[image]

[image]